# Accessing a variable that is outside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I have this simple code

```
 orm: function (req, res) {

    // Send a JSON response


       Noder.query('SELECT * FROM crud ', function(err, results) {
        var all_rows = Noder.query('SELECT count(*) from crud ', function(err, the_rows) {
        return the_rows;
        });

         res.view('noder/orm', {
            layout: 'layout',
            allr:all_rows,
            post:results,
            title: 'This is the hi page title. '
        }); 
      });
   },
```

which i am using to fetch all rows in a mysql table. However inside that function,i want to have another function that counts how many rows there are in the table.My variable var all_rows shows me undefined when i try displaying it. How can i solve this?.

Comment: Do not return `the_rows`, put `res.view('noder/orm', {
            layout: 'layout',
            allr:all_rows,
            post:results,
            title: 'This is the hi page title. '
        }); ` inside `Noder.query` success callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are accessing the value of `all_rows` before the inner-query has returned.

`Noder.query` is an asynchronous function, and as such, its execution will be delayed until the query itself is completed. Meanwhile, your `orm` function will continue merrily down and call `res.view` while your inner query is still processing.

To fix this, you can call `res.view` from inside your inner query.